# c# cross join two same type of lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, linq-to-entities

So here I have some code, which works ok. But I want to change the `select` part to something else, I am not sure what other methods I can use any help would be appreciated.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var all = new List<People>{new People{Id = 1, Name = "andy1", Age = null}, new People{Id = 2, Name = "andy2", Age = null}, new People{Id = 3, Name = "andy3", Age = null}, new People{Id = 4, Name = "andy4", Age = null}, };
        var someOfThem = new List<People>{new People{Id = 1, Name = null, Age = 1}, new People{Id = 2, Name = null, Age = 1},new People{Id = 3, Name = null, Age = 1}};
        var test = someOfThem.Select(c =>
        {
            c.Name = all.Find(a => a.Id == c.Id).Name;
            return c;
        });
        foreach (var item in test)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}={2}", item.Id, item.Name, item.Age);
    }
}

public class People
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int? Age
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And here is the result.

```
1=andy1=1
2=andy2=1
3=andy3=1
```

I am just wondering is there another way to achieve the same result but a more elegant way? or an easier way?

```cs
        var test = someOfThem.Select(c =>
        {
            c.Name = all.Find(a => a.Id == c.Id).Name;
            return c;
        });
```

**Update**
Sorry I did not show my problem properly at first, I have updated my quesiton. Please have a look again.

Comment: you have `c.Id == c.Id` which will always be true

Comment: @Aggragoth, thank you for pointing out, I have changed.

Comment: also in the second code block d:

Comment: @Aggragoth, ok all done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Join (you can also use a dictionary, but I'm not going to show it):

Here's the syntax for join:

```
var test = someOfThem.Join(all, item => item.Id, element => element.Id, 
  (item, element) => new Person { 
    Id = item.Id ?? element.Id,
    Name = item.Name ?? element.Name,
    Age = item.Age ?? element.Age
  });
```

Comment: Sorry I did not show my problem properly at first, I have updated my quesiton. Please have a look again.

Comment: I do not think join will work, as join will either pick one list or the other, and what I want is mix them together. any help?

Comment: @AndySong Updated answer to fit your new question.

Comment: is this going to be faster than `var test = someOfThem.Select(c =>
        {
            c.Name = all.Find(a => a.Id == c.Id).Name;
            return c;
        });`?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't mutate the original collection.  Using what you had, try dumping someOfThem afterwards and you'll notice you've modified it.   You can also simplify the above if you know where you want each property to come from.  I just used the null coalescing operator because then I didn't have to care, but it is slightly slower -- very slightly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use C#'s LINQ keywords and more specifically, the `join` keyword assosciated with it:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var all = new List<People> { new People { Id = 1, Name = "andy1", }, new People { Id = 2, Name = "andy2", }, new People { Id = 3, Name = "andy3", }, new People { Id = 4, Name = "andy4", }, };
        var someOfThem = new List<People> { new People { Id = 1, Name = null, }, new People { Id = 2, Name = null, } };
        var test = from item in someOfThem
                   join element in all on item.Id equals element.Id
                   select element;

        foreach (var item in test)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", item.Id, item.Name);
    }
}

public class People
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The code version would be

```
var test = someOfThem.Join(all, item => item.Id, element => element.Id, (item, element) => element);
```

as shown in Robert's comment

Comment: thank you for your answer, can you please provide the methods syntax linq?

Comment: `var test = someOfThem.Join(all, item => item.Id, element => element.Id, (item, element) => element);`

Comment: Sorry I did not show my problem properly at first, I have updated my quesiton. Please have a look again.

Comment: I do not think join will work, as join will either pick one list or the other, and what I want is mix them together. any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your People class and use `Intersect`.

Or, create an EqualityComparer, that way your comparison logic is decoupled:

```cs
class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var all = new List<People> { new People { Id = 1, Name = "andy1", }, new People { Id = 2, Name = "andy2", }, new People { Id = 3, Name = "andy3", }, new People { Id = 4, Name = "andy4", }, };
        var someOfThem = new List<People> { new People { Id = 1, Name = null, }, new People { Id = 2, Name = null, } };

        var test = all.Intersect(someOfThem, new PeopleIdComparer()).ToList();

        foreach (var item in test)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", item.Id, item.Name);
    }
}

public class PeopleIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<People>
{
    public bool Equals(People x, People y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(People obj)
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(obj.Id);
    }
}

public class People
{
    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```